# Jquery slide down login menu doesnt work

Tags: jquery

i need to create a slide down menu for my login screen.
This is the code i have but it doesnt work.

Jquery:

```
$('document').ready(function ()
{
    $('#login').click(function ()
    {
        $('form').slideDown();
    });
});
```

Html:

```
<div id="login">
<p id="open">Login</p>
<form>
    <p>
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="password">Password: </label>
        <input type="text" name="password" id="password">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" >
    </p>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

on click of #open you need to open form:

for that add display:none in form first

and create click event for #open and in that event toggle form:

Html:

```
<div id="login">
    <p id="open">Login</p>
    <form style="display:none;">
        <p>
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="password">Password: </label>
            <input type="text" name="password" id="password">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" >
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#open').click(function ()
    {
        $('form').slideDown();
    });
});
```